# Prisma timesout whith large datasets

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma, fastify

I have an app (Node.js (Fastify), postgres with prisma) that writes sales from an external onto the postgres db based on dates. Once the sales have been written the timestamps are written in a table in order to check later if that date has been queried (so if we request the sales for October 2019 it will check whether or not October 2019 has been queried before and return the sales from the db if that's the case or fetch from the external API, writes them on the db and write October 2019 on the date table for the next time).

My issue is when trying to get all the sales, which can be over several years. The way I do it right now is (please note that the only endpoint I can use with the API is year/month, so I have no other choice but to iterate my requests every month

1. Get the amount of months between first and last sale (for example, 97)
2. Loop over each month and check whether or not this month has been queried before
3. if it has been queried before, do nothing
4. If it has not been queried before, fetch this year/month combination from external API and write it on db
5. Once the loop has finished, get all the sales from the db in between those 2 dates

The issue I have is that while I paginated my endpoint, prisma timesout with some stores while upserting. Some months can have thousands of sales with relations for the products sold and I feel that that's where the issue is.

Here is the error message

> Timed out fetching a new connection from the connection pool. More info: http://pris.ly/d/connection-pool (Current connection pool timeout: 10, connection limit: 10)"

My question is, is it my logic that is bad and should be redone, or should I not write that many objects in the database, is there a best practice I'm missing ?

I did not provide code as it is working and I feel the issue lies in the logic more than the code itself but I will happily provide code if needed.

Comment: I can't understand if this application runs in serial or in parallel nor if you can run bulk queries or insert. Code would be helpful to. For sure I would start a job that preload all the data during the night or every hour instead of waiting for the sales people to query the data. Postgres supports millions of record

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon my upserts were done in parallel , but I thought prisma/postgres could handle that. In the hand I decided to go with a job that does the work in the background. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Prisma has a connection pool, which you need to tell heroku's connection limit.

You'll need a ".profile" file in your root folder containing:

```
export DATABASE_URL="$DATABASE_URL?connection_limit=10&pool_timeout=0"
```

".profile" is like .bashrc or .zshrc. Its content will be executed on startup of your server. The line above will overwrite the standard env variable for databases on heroku.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know for the connection pool (this is not running on Heroku btw). As far as I know Prisma sets the default connection pool based on the amount of CPU cores. I thought prisma should be able to handle 15,000 upserts no problem with the default pool and that the problem was more in my logic. For this reason I did't want to just raise the connection pool.